# spring security: login page does not load static resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a problem with my web application done with spring security, it has a login page.
my configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return new MyUserDetailsService();
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> auth.requestMatchers("api/v1/apps/welcome", "api/v1/apps/new-user").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("api/v1/apps/**").authenticated())
                .formLogin(form -> form
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .permitAll())
                .build();

    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

when the login page loads, only html is loaded and the css file and js are missing. As I understand it, this is due to the differentiation of roles. How do I make static resources available to all users? All resources are located in the resources/static folder.

i tried to do this:

```
.requestMatchers("/static/**").permitAll()
```

but not working...

Comment: try .anyRequest().permitAll()

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the path to the css file. It is necessary to specify

```
<link href="/css/file.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

then in the configuration file you need to write

```
.requestMatchers("/js/**", "/css/**", "/fonts/**").permitAll()
```

or

```
.anyRequest().permitAll()
```